# Missing minutes in strtotime() / timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

Could somebody please take a look into my code:

```
$godzinaRozpoczecia = "10:35";
$dateStampGodzinaRozpoczecia = strtotime($godzinaRozpoczecia);
echo date("H:m", $dateStampGodzinaRozpoczecia);
RESULT: 10:08
var_dump($godzinaRozpoczecia);
RESULT:    string(5) "10:35"
```

What is wrong? Why do I have *minutes* missing? In `var_dump` everything seems to be fine. The same issue occurs when I retrieve the time from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function specifies the following format for `"H:m"`:

> - H: 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
> - m: Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros

So you're actually showing the month here, you're looking for `i`:

> - i: Minutes with leading zeros

You may have been confused with the format used for the `strtotime()`, `DateTime` and `date_create()` [formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php). They are different from the `date()` formats (for some illogical reason).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
date("H:i", $dateStampGodzinaRozpoczecia);
```

//m is for month.current month is August that is only it gives you 08 as aswer